# How to keep small part of page uncahced in page out put caching

Tags: asp.net, caching

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ OutputCache Duration="10" Location="Server" VaryByParam="none" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Welcome to ASP.NET!
    </h2>
    <p>
        To learn more about ASP.NET visit <a href="http://www.asp.net" title="ASP.NET Website">
            www.asp.net</a>.
    </p>
    <p>
        This is cached date text
        <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </p>
     <p>
        This is uncached date text
        <asp:Label ID="lblDate1" EnableViewState="false" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </p>
    <p>
        You can also find <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=152368&amp;clcid=0x409"
            title="MSDN ASP.NET Docs">documentation on ASP.NET at MSDN</a>.
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

In above code I want that only lblDate1 value should change whenever I will refresh the page How can I acheive this.Currently both control values are geting cahced.

Answer (score 0):

Since the page is cached, well - the entire page is cached, and nothing in this call will be retreived again from the server until the cache is invalidated.

You could solve it by doing an ajax call with javascript on document load that gets the updated value from a REST service (or just simulate a service by returning json formatted string from an aspx page), and then update the date value from javascript.